# Tool identification

Tags: tools

I was cleaning out my garage today and found this old set of bicycle tools. I don't know what they are or what they're supposed to be used for on a bicycle.  Can you identify them for me?

[image: Image of various bicycle tools]

Comment: Excellent question - thank you for joining this stack to ask.

Comment: For any people with many of the combination spanner tools (far right), I used them as fishing weights. You can cut it to different lengths to get different weights and, due to their shape, grip well on river/shore/lake floor.

Comment: Where's the banana?

Comment: @Strawberry the emergency banana for scale got eaten on the last ride.   It was delicious.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The tool on the far left is potentially a tire spoon for removing a tire. I don't think that was its original use as it looks more like a tobacco can or possible a a patch adhesive lid tool. the second appears to be a combination flat head screwdriver and an allen wrench. The third is a brake adjustment aid. It squeezes the brake pads to the rim to allow for proper pad placement or cable adjustment. The far right is a multi size wrench. It is almost but not completely obsolete as most bikes now use allen head hardware.

Comment: I suspect that the second has two different allen sizes.  Or perhaps one end is square.  In any event, it's a wrench.  And you're right that the tire tool appears to have been MacGyvered from a can opener.

Comment: Thanks.  This is helpful.  Since all the bikes in my household are now 6 years old or less (and I won't likely be doing brake adjustments myself) these are useless, but I may keep them for posterity.  It is possible that the one on the left is a paint can opener.  I remember getting a paint can opener when buying some paint a decade ago.  It might have gotten mixed in with bike tools by accident.

Comment: On closer inspection the can opener may also  have a bottle opener built into the handle.

Comment: Number two looks like something you'd find from a particular Swedish furniture manufacturer...

Comment: If the second tool it what I think it is (an ikea hex key) then i'm pretty sure both ends are the same size. They are really crappy hex keys too, I have had at least one peice of Ikea furniture where the supplied key couldn't apply enough torque to get the fastners in and just rounded out.

Answer (score 31):

From left to right:

1. Paint can lid opener
2. Combination Allen key
3. Third hand brake tool
4. Combination wrench

Comment: Confirming #1 is an opener for a paint can, should go nowhere near a tyre or rim unless its last-resort.  Seems to be extra-bent too, perhaps overstressed, or someone made a bodgy tool for extra-stubborn tyres (marathons perhaps?)

Comment: #4  is also called a "dog bone spanner" because it looks vaguely like a dog's bone.   They lack in leverage because of length, and shape is awkward to use, but better than nothing.

Comment: The combination Allen key looks like it's from Ikea

Comment: #2 & #4 are probably meant to travel along with the cyclist, right? I'd think you would want to use normal full size tools back in the shop / garage, space permitting...

Comment: You forgot #1's more important function, it can be used to open beer

Answer (score 0):

The tool on the right side is a spanner with several sizes. Not exactly a top quality tool as far as spanner go, but this one was once very common in Germany. It is short and it was standard to have it in a small bag hanging underneath the back side of the saddle. I am not sure whether it is still sold nowadays.